# can I solve analytically or numerically the equation $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=0$ with the following boundaries?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, boundary-value-problem, electromagnetism

I was wondering if I can solve somehow the charge conservation equation on a specific domain and boundary conditions.
There is no time dependency, thus the equation reads:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=0$$
Or in other words:
$$\frac{\partial J_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial J_y}{\partial y}=0$$
The domain is a rectangle with edges $(a,b)$.
I'll define the edges as follows
$t$ - Is the top edge
$b$ - Is the bottom edge
$l$ - Is the left edge
$r$ - Is the right edge

The $x$ axis is perpendicular to the left and right edges and the $y$ axis is perpendicular to the top and bottom edges.

The left and bottom edges are isolated boundaries.
The top edge is where all current should come out.
and the right edge is the current source.
So, the only boundary conditions that I know are:
$$J_y(b)=0$$
$$J_x(l)=0$$
$$J_x(t)=0$$
$$J_x(r)=f(y)$$

Where $f(y)$ is a known function.
So, is this kind of differential equation is solvable?
And, does these four boundary conditions are enough to produce a unique solution?
And if so, how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It has infinitely many answers...Don't you have any other constraint on this problem?

Comment: If you think of it physically, you're trying to figure out how electricity flows across a conducting plate without knowing, for instance, whether the plate is homogeneous.

Comment: By homogeneous, you mean that the conductivity is constant?
If so, unfortunately it's not homogeneous.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. The reason is that the problem is not well-posed. The reason for this is that you are trying to find two functions $J_x$ and $J_y$ (because $\bf J$ is a vector with two components) but you have only one equation that $J_x$ and $J_y$ should satisfy.

It is possible to demonstrate that you have infinite solutions. In particular, if ${\bf J}(x,y)=(J_x(x,y),J_y(x,y))^T$ is a solution of $\nabla \cdot {\bf J}=0$, then ${\bf J}(x,y)=(J_x(x,y),J_y(x,y)+h(x))^T$ is again a solution for any functions $h(x)$ with the only condition $h(b)=0$.

Comment: Does more boundary conditions will be enough? or will I have to provide additional equation?

Comment: Yes you have one only equation $\nabla \cdot \, {\bf J}=0$ and two unknown functions, $J_x$ and $J_y$. So you have to impose another condition, another equation.